# R: Identifying distinct rows on dates within intervals and scoring rows based on occurence

Tags: r, date, dplyr, conditional-statements, intervals

Dear geniuses of Stack

I find myself in need of help with writing rather advanced code. I have a data frame with three columns; a unique ID column (**IDcol**), a result column (**Result**), and a date for the results (**Date**).
There are 3 types of results, N1, N2 and N4. These can be measured over time for each ID. My data could look something like this:

```
   IDcol Result       Date
1    ID1     N1 2018-06-11
2    ID1     N2 2018-06-11
3    ID1     N4 2018-01-01
4    ID1     N1 2012-06-11
5    ID1     N2 2012-06-11
6    ID2     N1 2016-04-23
7    ID2     N2 2016-04-23
8    ID2     N4 2015-01-05
9    ID3     N1 2015-11-24
10   ID3     N2 2015-11-24
11   ID3     N4 2013-05-05
12   ID4     N1 2015-01-01
13   ID4     N2 2015-01-01
14   ID4     N1 2014-05-06
15   ID4     N2 2014-05-06
16   ID5     N1 2016-04-04
17   ID5     N2 2014-04-04
18   ID5     N4 2012-04-04
```

As you can see for ID1, N1 and N2 is measured twice on two dates - N4 is also measured in between. The code needs to "scan" for the *earliest* dates where N1 and N2 are measured. The scoring system could give these occurrences a score of 2. However, if N4 occurs within minus 1 year of N1 and N2 measurements, the code should "scan" for this and prioritize this as a "higher score". So for the example of ID1, the desired output would look like this:

```
  IDcol Result       Date score
1   ID1     N1 2018-06-11     3
2   ID1     N2 2018-06-11     3
3   ID1     N4 2018-01-01     3
```

Meaning that even though earlier N1 and N2 results were measured, they were dropped due to N4 also being measured within one year of the later measures of N1 and N2. ID2 is kept as an example, where the code should keep the rows for ID2. For ID3, N4 is measured but falls out of the minus one-year interval, and the row should thus be dropped. For ID4, the earliest measurements should be prioritized over the latest, and lastly, for ID5 - there are too many discrepancies between dates where Results are measured. Effectively, the desired output should look like this:

```
   IDcol Result       Date score
1    ID1     N1 2018-06-11     3
2    ID1     N2 2018-06-11     3
3    ID1     N4 2018-01-01     3
4    ID2     N1 2016-04-23     3
5    ID2     N2 2016-04-23     3
6    ID2     N4 2015-01-05     3
7    ID3     N1 2015-11-24     2
8    ID3     N2 2015-11-24     2
9    ID4     N1 2014-05-06     2
10   ID4     N2 2014-05-06     2
```

I have tried with dplyr with the following:

```
IDcol <- c("ID1", "ID1", "ID1",
           "ID1", "ID1", 
           "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", 
           "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", 
           "ID4", "ID4", 
           "ID4", "ID4",
           "ID5", "ID5", "ID5") 

Result <- c("N1", "N2", "N4",
            "N1", "N2",
            "N1", "N2", "N4",
            "N1", "N2", "N4",
            "N1", "N2", 
            "N1", "N2",
            "N1", "N2",  "N4")
Date <- c("2018-06-11","2018-06-11", "2018-01-01",
          "2012-06-11", "2012-06-11",
          "2016-04-23", "2016-04-23", "2015-01-05",
          "2015-11-24", "2015-11-24", "2013-05-05",
          "2015-01-01", "2015-01-01",
          "2014-05-06", "2014-05-06",
          "2016-04-04", "2014-04-04", "2012-04-04")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(IDcol, Result, Date))
df$Date <- ymd(df$Date)

df1 <- df %>% group_by(IDcol, Date) %>% 
mutate(score=case_when(length(Result) > 3 & Date[Result=="N4"] %within% interval (Date[Result=="N1"-duration(1,units=years)) ~ 3,
"N1" %in% Result & "N2" %in% Result ~ 2,
TRUE ~ 0,
)) %>% filter(score > 0) %>% group_by(IDcol) %>% arrange(desc(score), Date,.by_group=TRUE) %>% filter(Date == first(Date)) %>% ungroup()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I believe this gives you your desired output. With problems like this I like to simplify the logic/code a bit by separating some information into a different df first and using filter.

```
cutoff.data <- df %>% 
  filter(Result != 'N4') %>% 
  group_by(IDcol) %>% 
  summarise(earliest = min(Date)) %>% 
  mutate(n4.cutoff = earliest - dyears(1)) %>% 
  select(-earliest)

df %>% 
  left_join(cutoff.data) %>% 
  group_by(IDcol) %>% 
  mutate(n4.row = ifelse(Result == 'N4',1,0),
         n4.check = sum(n4.row)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% # grouping messes up the following ifelse step
  mutate(score = ifelse(n4.check == 1 & Date[Result == 'N4'] >= n4.cutoff, 3, 2)) %>% 
  group_by(IDcol) %>% # but then grouping is required to get lowest score per ID
  mutate(score = min(score))

# A tibble: 18 x 7
# Groups:   IDcol [5]
   IDcol Result Date       n4.cutoff           n4.row n4.check score
   <fct> <fct>  <date>     <dttm>               <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 ID1   N1     2018-06-11 2011-06-11 18:00:00      0        1     3
 2 ID1   N2     2018-06-11 2011-06-11 18:00:00      0        1     3
 3 ID1   N4     2018-01-01 2011-06-11 18:00:00      1        1     3
 4 ID1   N1     2012-06-11 2011-06-11 18:00:00      0        1     3
 5 ID1   N2     2012-06-11 2011-06-11 18:00:00      0        1     3
 6 ID2   N1     2016-04-23 2015-04-23 18:00:00      0        1     2
 7 ID2   N2     2016-04-23 2015-04-23 18:00:00      0        1     2
 8 ID2   N4     2015-01-05 2015-04-23 18:00:00      1        1     2
 9 ID3   N1     2015-11-24 2014-11-23 18:00:00      0        1     2
10 ID3   N2     2015-11-24 2014-11-23 18:00:00      0        1     2
11 ID3   N4     2013-05-05 2014-11-23 18:00:00      1        1     2
12 ID4   N1     2015-01-01 2013-05-05 18:00:00      0        0     2
13 ID4   N2     2015-01-01 2013-05-05 18:00:00      0        0     2
14 ID4   N1     2014-05-06 2013-05-05 18:00:00      0        0     2
15 ID4   N2     2014-05-06 2013-05-05 18:00:00      0        0     2
16 ID5   N1     2016-04-04 2013-04-03 18:00:00      0        1     2
17 ID5   N2     2014-04-04 2013-04-03 18:00:00      0        1     2
18 ID5   N4     2012-04-04 2013-04-03 18:00:00      1        1     2
```

Comment: Hi Bowhaven, thank you for your contribution; it is appreciated. I see that your code was able to identify some of the data "hierarchy" correctly, for example for ID1. The score is annotated as 3. For ID1 in row five and six, it is also annotated as 3. Ideally these rows should be removed. ID5 should also be omitted, due to not having N1 and N2 measured on the same date. In the case of ID3, the row with N4 should also be removed - owing to the fact, that it was measured outside a one-year period of N1 and N2 in this case. Do you have further suggestions to add to the code? Best wishes

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused on the logic you require. You mentioned finding the earliest N1 and N2 occurences in your original post but it also seems you want to find the latest too - Do you specifically want to check if N4 occurs a year before the *earliest* or *latest* N1/N2 measurements? Then we can remove using filter based on your answer to that.

Comment: Thank you for getting back! I appreciate you taking the time to try and understand this thoroughly! So ideally, I want to check if N4 occurs up to one year before any N1 and N2 measurements. If it does not, the code should just "catch" the earliest date where N1 and N2 occur simultaneously. Again, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Ah okay thanks for clarifying, it seems the whole process is dependent on checking if N1 and N2 'pairs' are on the same date. But I can't see an easy way to identify these pairs given that there could be any number of N1s and N2s occurring on different dates. Good luck with the problem!